# Wait for user to press on confirm/deny then do something

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular so bear with me. I have 3 files: WarningComponent (shows a warning modal (bootstrap)), modalService (this will open the modals) and votingComponent.

In the votingComponent there is a button: vote. When this button is pressed, the WarningComponent open (with the modalService). The Warning Component has 2 button's: Confirm and Deny.

What I want is: When the user presses on Confirm, the function postSelectionChoice() should fire in votingComponent.

I have tried to implement this with Promise and Observable, but didn't work for me or I've implemented those  wrong...

votingComponent.ts

```
  private showWarning() {
    // This gets fired when the user presses on Vote
    this.modalService.openModal(ModalType.WARNING,"test");
  }

  private postSelectionChoice() {
   // This should fire when the user presses on Confirm in the WarningComponent

  }
```

Modal.Service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  public openModal(modal: ModalType, message: string) {
    let modalRef :NgbModalRef = null;
    if(modal == ModalType.ALERT) {
      modalRef = this.modalService.open(AlertModalComponent);
    } else if (modal == ModalType.WARNING) {
      modalRef = this.modalService.open(WarningModalComponent);
    } else if (modal == ModalType.SUCCES) {
      modalRef = this.modalService.open(SuccesModalComponent);
    }
    modalRef.componentInstance.message = message;
  }

  // Tried this as example...
  public getConfirmation(status: Warningstatus) : Promise<Boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(status == Warningstatus.YES) {
          console.log("trueeee");
          resolve(true);
      } else if(status == Warningstatus.NO) {
        console.log("falseeee");
          resolve(false);
      }
  });
  }
}
```

WarningComponent.ts

```
export class WarningModalComponent {

  @Input() message;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
  }

  public confirmButton() {
    // This gets fired when the user presses the confirm button
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

votingComponent.ts

```
import { NgbModal, NgbModalOptions } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

In constructor:

```
constructor(        
    private _modalService: NgbModal
) { }
```

Show your modal:

```
showWarning() {
    const modalRef = this._modalService.open(WarningModalComponent, { size: 'lg' });
    modalRef.componentInstance.SomeInputDataToModal = yourdata;
    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
        if (result) {                
            console.log("trueeee");
        }
    },
        (reason) => { });
    }
```

In your WarningComponent.ts:

```
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

    constructor(
        public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
    ) { }


    onClose() {
        this.activeModal.close(false);
    }

    onDismiss() {
        this.activeModal.dismiss(false);
    }

    onResult() {
        // do something with you data and send result
        this.activeModal.close(yourreturndatatoparent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

modal-Control-service.ts

```
 public showConfirmModal: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
 simpleObservable: Observable<{}>;
 reAction: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); 

 confirmDialog(action: string, objectValue: string, objectType: string) {

  let simpleObservable;
  const reAction = this.reAction;
  const promise = Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

  simpleObservable = new Observable((observer) => {

    observer.complete();
    if (reAction.value !== null) {
      resolve(reAction.value);
    }
    reject('Invalid action');
  });

  });

  this.simpleObservable = simpleObservable;
  this.showConfirmModal.next(true);
  return promise; 
 }

 confirm() {
  this.reAction.next(true);
  this.subscribe = this.simpleObservable.subscribe();
  this.subscribe.unsubscribe();
 }

 decline() {
  this.reAction.next(false);
  this.subscribe = this.simpleObservable.subscribe();
  this.subscribe.unsubscribe();
  }
```

modal-component.ts

```
 modalRef: BsModalRef;
     constructor(public modalControl: ModalControlService, public modalService: BsModalService, ) {

modalControl.showConfirmModal.subscribe((nextValue) => {
  // this will happen on every change
  if (nextValue) {
    this.modal.show();
  }
});
  }
```

in here I'm using modal in ngx-bootstrop library.